# How to make an icon button in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, button, reference, icons

I know how to draw a button in C++ but how would i make an icon on it can someone post source or give reference please? by SendMessage() or if not that way just please paste
Please need easier anwsers without so many files im new a bit

Comment: please specify the GUI API you are using. Win32? MFC? Qt? I assume win32 from your SendMessage comment. But please clarify.

Comment: I suppose we can assume that you're using MFC from your accepted answer :-) It'd be great to say thank you.

Comment: Lost punctuation along the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MFC then I would recommend you to use the following `CButton` method `SetIcon`:

```
CButton myButton;

// Create an icon button.
myButton.Create(_T("My button"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_ICON, 
   CRect(10,10,60,50), pParentWnd, 1);

// Set the icon of the button to be the system question mark icon.
myButton.SetIcon( ::LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION) );
```

This works very well.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're new, you may also wish to consult the MSDN Library. You can find information on [Button Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951(VS.85).aspx) (see, specifically, the BS ICON and BS BITMAP styles) and the [BM_SETIMAGE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761822(VS.85).aspx) .

Answer (score 2):

send BM_SETIMAGE message, and pass loaded image handle to lParam.

```
button1 = CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON", L"&Button", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | BS_BITMAP, 20, 50, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 600, NULL, NULL);

hImg = LoadImageW(NULL, L"test123.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
SendMessageW(button1, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) hImg);
```

P.S: you need to use BS_BITMAP flag when CreateWindow()