# How is to create button with icon in WINAPI

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, button, icons

I have a button.

```
HWND button = CreateWindow("button", "test_text", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 500, 500, window, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

"window" is my HWND variable of my window.

How can I add icon like this
`HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("1.png"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);`
to my "button" variable?

I serched information about my problem in the Inthernet, but I can't find anything, that can work.

Comment: The documentation covers this. See [Button Control Overviews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-button-button-control-overviews).

Comment: There is a C++ answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632919/how-to-make-an-icon-button-in-c) if that points you the right way.

Comment: Could you please check Remy Lebeau‘s answer? You could try to use `LoadImage` to load an icon or bitmap.You couldn't load `.png`  via LoadImage directly. And then use `BM_SETIMAGE message` to associate a new image (icon or bitmap) with the button.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't use `LoadImage()` to load a `.png` file as an `HBITMAP`. See questions like [How would I load a PNG image using Win32/GDI (no GDI+ if possible)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567875/) and [How would I draw a PNG image using LoadImage and StretchDIBits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568057/) for alternatives.

Second, once you do have your image loaded as an `HBITMAP` (or `HICON`), you can assign it to the button using the [`BM_SETIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-setimage) message.